# When Do UI Tests Happen in a React App?

Tags: reactjs, integration-testing, puppeteer

So I understand the flow of unit testing, and enzyme/dom testing within a react project.  The tests pull components, mock what's necessary, and then these tests can be run manually, or through a CI tool or git hooks.

However, as I'm reading into and writing Puppeteer UI tests, I'm a little confused.  Most seem to require the entire server to be running, as they rely on localhost:3000.  In other words, *testing requires more than just running the test file*.

So I suppose my question is

1. Am I misunderstanding **how** UI tests work, and is there a way to pull isolated/mocked components, so that these tests can be run just by running the test file

or

2. Am I misunderstanding **when** UI tests are supposed to be done.  Are they something that are run manually by devs, infrequently?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about unit testing your UI components, you should use enzyme and Jest. You should be able to mount your isolated, individual components into their own test files, and have them run automatically.

https://facebook.github.io/jest/

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-react.html

Puppeteer fires up an actual headless browser. Here are the docs on integrating it with Jest. In short, everything from the puppeteer side is set up globally before any react is run. Then an actual browser request is made.

https://github.com/smooth-code/jest-puppeteer
https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/puppeteer.html

Comment: I am already doing enzyme and jest testing, as stated in the question.  Does Puppeteer/UI testing fall into a different category though?  Do they depend on things outside running the test, like having the webpack server running?  When does Puppeteer testing happen in the lifecycle of a project?

Comment: Gotcha. Updated my answer.

Comment: So are UI tests meant to be done with the same consistency and automation as unit tests?  And what if the ui depends on calls from a back end service?  Or an authentication service?  Or should UI tests be run manually by a dev every so often as a manual check?

Comment: it's up to the team. Certainly not as often as unit tests, since they are slow. Perhaps run them before a big merge or once a day. My team runs them daily.